# Castle Windsor Interceptor and Unit Of Work

Tags: nhibernate, castle-windsor

Is Castle Windsor's Inteceptor mechanism considered to be a good/effective way of implementing the Unit of Work pattern?

My project involves Castle Windsor, the NHibernate Facility and of course NHibernate - all used in self-hosted WCF services.

Each service method normally requests from the Windsor container an instance of a helper class into which the WCF call is delegated. The helper class has an ISessionManager constructor argument which Windsor resolves via the NHibernate Facility.

The trouble is, the helper class is doing too much work. It has both logic and data access intermingled which means its difficult (virtually impossible) to test and difficult to read.

What I want is to re-arrange responsibilities

I don't want the WCF helper to know anything about transactions or sessions, so no ISessionManager constructor arg, no references to transactions and no ISession.

In order for the WCF helper to do data access, its going to have to rely on a new helper, dare I call it a DAO? or God forbid a repository, on which will be methods for fetching, querying, and possibly saving domain objects.

The problem with returning NHibernate proxied objects from a DAO is that if the session is closed before the entity is returned, any subsequent attempt to access collections on the domain object from the client code will result in an exception as the session is no longer there to be used to lazily fetch the required data. It's obvious really, but everyone new to  NHibernate must hit this issue.

So if DAOs and Repos cant close the session, what does?

What I need is one NHibernate session per WCF service operation call, where several DAOs or Respositories can call OpenSession as much as they like, but they all get the same session, and ideally, any attempt to dispose the session would be ignored unless its the last Dispose. Not sure about the last bit, but maybe DAOs and repos just call ISessionManager.OpenSession and leave it to something else to flush and dispose the session.

I thought maybe I could use an interceptor which takes an ISessionManager, opens a session and starts a transaction, forwards the invocation, then if no exception occurs, commits the transaction and disposes the session, otherwise rolls back the transaction if any exception occurs.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> So if DAOs and Repos cant close the
>   session, what does?session, what does?

Services own units of work, not DAOs.  They demark units of work.

Spring manages transactions using AOP, so interceptors sound like a good bet for transaction management to me.

As far as sessions go, those are UI concepts, so it ought to be the web or desktop UI controller that opens the session, marshals services to fulfill use cases, and closes the session when it's complete.

Answer (score 1):

Castle.Service.Transactions also ties well together with the rest of the castle stack and allow you to use AOP to handle transactions.

Have a look at v3!
https://github.com/haf/Castle.Services.Transaction

And the wiki there!

I also created a new NHibernate Facility:

https://github.com/haf/Castle.Facilities.NHibernate/wiki/NHibernate-Facility---Quick-Start

Comment: Thanks, this seems worth a look; I'll investigate.